# How to execute sql Python script in Windows command Prompt?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.7

I have a simple script that uses sqlite3 in Python.

However, when I run this from cmd.exe in Windows I get an "Open With" window. If I click 'cancel' it says "Access is denied." in cmd.exe.

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("test_database.db")
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE People(FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, Age INT)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO People VALUES('Ron','Obvious',42)")
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I can run Python scripts fine from cmd.exe. I just have this problem because I'm using sqlite?

(Also, I have the sqlite path in PATH)

How can I stop this "Open with" window appearing, and actually get my script to run correctly from cmd.exe?

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with Python; I doubt this has anything to do with `sqlite`. *Do* use absolute paths, don't rely on the current working directory, this can vary widely with how a script is run.

Comment: How are you trying to execute it?  Seems like you are basically trying to "run" a file that your system doesn't know what to do with (i.e. asks you).  Should be able to use `python C:\yourscript.py`.

Comment: @nerdwaller thanks, that solved it actually... I usually just run "<filename>.py" and that works usually. But it seems that breaks if I use sqlite :-s

Answer (score 0):

Running myscript.py in cmd does not work if I use import sqlite. Instead, I ran "python myscript.py" and the script runs fine.

Thanks to @nerdwaller.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, to execute a script that needs an interpreter, you can either run the interpreter manually:

```
C:\> python myscript.py
```

or ensure that `.py` files are associated with `python.exe` (if you get the "open with" window, it's likely that this was not done), then run the script with `start`, which is the equivalent of double-clicking:

```
C:\> start /b/wait myscript.py
```

or change the `PATHEXT` environment variable to allow executing files with that extension directly (this behaves then the same as the above `start` command):

```
C:\> set pathext=%pathext%;.py
C:\> myscript
```